# Пример реализации  callback-вызова из c++ из ios  в unity3d

Tags: c#, unity3d, ios

Есть у кого-нибудь готовый пример реализации  `callback`-вызова из c++ из ios обратно в `unity3d` (не `UnitySendMessage`, а с любыми параметрами)? Или где про это можно почитать подробно.
Т.е. вызов через делегаты C#?

Answer (score 1):

**C#**

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System;
using AOT;

public delegate void SDKCorePluginCallbackDelegate(string inparam);

public class SDKCorePlugin
{   
#if UNITY_EDITOR
    private static void _SDKCorePluginInitPlayer (string url,string playerName,SDKCorePluginCallbackDelegate fp)
    {
        Debug.Log ("SDKCorePlugin: Application.platform==RuntimePlatform.OSXEditor||RuntimePlatform.AndroidEditor!!!");
    }
#else
    #if UNITY_ANDROID
        [DllImport ("unity_bridge")]
    #elif UNITY_IPHONE
    [DllImport ("__Internal")]
    private static extern void _SDKCorePluginInitPlayer (string url,string playerName,SDKCorePluginCallbackDelegate fp);
    #endif
#endif


    // Starts lookup for some bonjour registered service inside specified domain
    public static void SDKCorePluginInitPlayer (string requestURL,string playerName,string objectName, string methodName,SDKCorePluginCallbackDelegate fp)
    {   
        _SDKCorePluginInitPlayer(requestURL,playerName,fp);
    }
    [MonoPInvokeCallback (typeof (SDKCorePluginCallbackDelegate))]
    public static void CallBackDataDelegate(string inparam)
    {
        inst.ResultText.text=inparam;
    }
}
```

**C++**

```
typedef void ( *ANSWERCB )(char*);

// When native code plugin is implemented in .mm / .cpp file, then functions
// should be surrounded with extern "C" block to conform C function naming rules
extern "C" {    
    void _SDKCorePluginInitPlayer(const char* url,const char *playerName,ANSWERCB fp)
    {
        [[SDKCoreClient GetSharedClient] initPlayer:CreateNSString(url) playername:CreateNSString(playerName)];
        [[SDKCoreClient GetSharedClient] setCallBackParams: fp];
    }
}
```

Вся суть в `using AOT;` и `MonoPInvokeCallback`